# WebDriverIO 6 &ndash; $ works fine, $ doesn't work in iframe

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I use WebDriverIO and try to access and click 2nd li tag inside iframe like this;
HTML Image:
[image: HTML Image].
It's no iframe-id, li-id.

Now it works the following code

```
describe('research test', () => {
    it ('click object in iframe test', () => {
        browser.url('http://localhost/test/html/index.html');
        browser.pause(2000);
        browser.switchToFrame(0);
        $$('[class="inside-list-menu"]')[1].click(); 
        browser.pause(5000);
    });
});
```

But I want to change code of the following part

```
 $$ ('[class = "inside-list-menu"]') [1] .click ();
```

To

```
 $ ('[class = "inside-list-menu"]') [1] .click ();
```

but it failed.

I want to know

1. Why $ doesn't work?
2. Other way 2nd li tag is able to click start with $.

I'm using WebDriverIO version: 6. 14. 5 // Browser: Chrome // OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a significant difference between $$ and $. To understand that better, please try to understand findElement and findElements from [here](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/findelement-in-selenium).

In short, $$ returns an array of elements while $ returns first element that matches the selector.

Based on the return type of $$, you will select an element from array of elements using its index ( `[1]` in your case). The return type of $ is an element and when you use index to select it, it is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Thank you Raju. 
I understand better now the difference between $$ and $.
Does it means if I use $, it must have unique key like id or name or class?
I changed unique class name on HTML like inside-list-menu1, inside-list-menu2,... and `$('[class="inside-list-menu2"]').click();` worked.

Comment: Ah! I changed testcode to `$('li=inside iframe menu3').click();` and it works without class name change! Thank you!

Comment: Hi @assezPierre, Glad that it worked for you. There is no hard rule that the selector inside $ has to be id or class which is unique. If you pass unique selector, it will select the same element every time. if you pass a selector of multiple elements, it will select the first occurrence of it.